# Magento2.3.0 :When merge and minify js and css after set production mode not working my admin panel and frontend css lacking

Tags: javascript, magento2.3, css, admin-panel, production-mode

I am using Magento2.3.0 community version  When merge and minify js and css after set production mode not working my admin panel and front end css lacking if any one know what is actual issue reply me .I apply all command in our production side.

Comment: Have you deployed static content in correct locale?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 Backend option to merge and minify js are useless. Please try the advance bundling of js provided in magento 2 docs using nodejs and r.js

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/performance-best-practices/advanced-js-bundling.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd you run static content deploy with different locales and show errors you might be able to see some errors

`php -d display_errors=1 -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_GB --theme Magento/luma`

Replace luma with your theme and en_GB with locale you are using. Could be different between frontend and backend.